# Integration Testing Adding a database file to my test project .How can I do it

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to do some integration testing. At the moment I have some scripts that run once per assembly that create the db if not exists and populate it.

I thought it would be better if I could add a databaseFile to the test project and then just populate and clear the db accordingly. Even if this is not the best way 
How do I add a database file eg "MyTestDB.mdf to my project. I am using VS 2010 premium Edition.

Suggestions?

Comment: Which database are you using, and which version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some experiments with this a couple of years ago and arrived at the conclusion that the fastest way to integration test against SQL Server is to have the database itself (including schema) as an [Immutable Shared Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html#Immutable%20Shared%20Fixture), but without any data in.

As part of [Fixture Teardown](http://xunitpatterns.com/fixture%20teardown.html), all tables are truncated, leaving a clean database for the next test case. Each test case fill the database with the data it needs as part of building up its Fixture. [A few years back I described this approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/01/31/dataaccesscomponenttestingredux.aspx) and it's still the best that I know of.

I've also experimented with attaching and detaching database files, but it turned out that the above process was faster.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.I will look at those links in a minute.Is there any specific link on how to attach and detach db files in a unittest scenario.I might need to show both approaches.Thanks again for your time

Comment: Just connect to the server and issue the appropriate T-SQL commands. It used to be sp_attach_db, but that's deprecated so now you should use CREATE DATABASE [...] FOR ATTACH instead. sp_detach_db seems to still be the correct way of detaching database files...